# Lisp - bad argument type: numberp: nil

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I am writing a function that removes background mask from all mtext, however, I am getting a `bad argument type: numberp: nil` error after running the code:

```
(defun c:bgm ()
    (vl-load-com)
    (setq ss1 (ssget "X" '((0 . "MTEXT")(-4 . "<OR")(90 . 1)(90 . 3)(-4 . "OR>")))); selects all mtext with background mask on
    (setq sscount (sslength ss1))
    (repeat sscount
        (setq mtxtobj (entget (vlax-vla-object->ename (ssname ss1 counter))))
        (vla-put-backgroundfill mtxtobj :vlax-false)
        (entmod mtxtobj)
    )
)
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code:

1. If the `ssget` expression does not obtain a selection (i.e. if there are no objects present in the drawing which fulfil the selection criteria), then `ssget` will return `nil`, and consequently the `sslength` function will error when supplied with a null argument.

   To avoid this, test the value returned by the `ssget` function using an `if` statement before proceeding with the remaining code:

   ```
   (if (setq ss1 (ssget "_X" '((0 . "MTEXT") (-4 . "<OR") (90 . 1) (90 . 3) (-4 . "OR>"))))
       (progn
           (setq sscount (sslength ss1))
           ...
       )
   )
   ```
2. You reference the variable `counter` in your `ssname` function, which is not defined in the scope of the `c:bgm` function:

   ```
   (ssname ss1 counter)
   ```

   This should instead be `sscount` as defined earlier in your code.
3. You seem to be confused between entity names and vla-objects:

   - `ssname` returns an entity name, however, you are passing this to the `vlax-vla-object->ename` function, which converts a vla-object to an entity name.
   - You are using the `vla-put-backgroundfill` function to change the `backgroundfill` property of a vla-object, however, you are passing this function the variable defined by the value returned by `entget`, which is a DXF data list, not a vla-object.
   - You are using `entmod` to modify the DXF data assigned to the variable `mtxtobj` - this is not required when changing ActiveX properties of a vla-object.

---

Taking the above into consideration, I would suggest the following solution:

```
(defun c:bgm ( / cnt obj sel )
    (if (setq sel (ssget "_X" '((0 . "MTEXT") (-4 . "<OR") (90 . 1) (90 . 3) (-4 . "OR>"))))
        (repeat (setq cnt (sslength sel))
            (setq cnt (1- cnt)
                  obj (vlax-ename->vla-object (ssname sel cnt))
            )
            (vla-put-backgroundfill obj :vlax-false)
        )
    )
    (princ)
)
(vl-load-com) (princ)
```

Comment: I realized that after a few hours of posting the thread. Thanks so much for your help, much appreciated. Cheers mate

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably due to:

```
(ssname ss1 counter)
```

where counter is nil.
You should use sscount instead. You also have to decrement the sscount value to iterate through the selection set.

```
(defun c:bgm (/ ss1 sscount)
  (vl-load-com)
  (if (setq ss1 (ssget "X" '((0 . "MTEXT") (-4 . "<OR") (90 . 1) (90 . 3) (-4 . "OR>"))))
    (repeat (setq sscount (sslength ss1))
      (setq sscount (1- sscount)
        mtxtobj (vlax-vla-object->ename (ssname ss1 sscount))
      )
      (vla-put-backgroundfill mtxtobj :vlax-false)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Error still popped up but I found the solution! thanks anyway